# Question marked as duplicate

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I asked two questions.

1. [Is there a way to assign keys in the command pallet list to jump to desired item instead of the default item in sublime text?](https://superuser.com/questions/814178/is-there-a-way-to-assign-keys-in-the-command-pallet-list-to-jump-to-desired-item?noredirect=1#comment1066113_814178)
2. [How to find out which command corrosponds to which command pallet list items in sublime text?](https://superuser.com/questions/814179/how-to-find-out-which-command-corrosponds-to-which-command-pallet-list-items-in?lq=1)

One of them is marked as duplicate and I've been suggested to make a multi-part question instead. But IMHO they're two completely different questions. (except for maybe the same image I've used in both of them). [I've voiced my reason as to why they don't seem similar to me](https://superuser.com/questions/814178/is-there-a-way-to-assign-keys-in-the-command-pallet-list-to-jump-to-desired-item?noredirect=1#comment1065690_814178)

Should the "duplicate" flag be lifted, or should I do as suggested - make a multipart question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one person has flagged it as Duplicate, but the person doesn't have vote to close privileges. the question will remain open till 5 people with close vote privileges will vote to close.

Consequently, there's no duplicate flag on it to be lifted.

And no, it's better to have one question per post

Comment: Weird, it was actually marked duplicate when I made this post (The text that appears at top saying "This question may already have an answer here.."). (which is what made me make this post in the first place!)

Comment: @laggingreflex That banner means that there are pending duplicate close votes or recommend closure flags against it, but not enough to close it. Remember, if you see no "marked as duplicate" banner (or "put on hold" or "closed" for that matter) just below your question, it's not closed.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi thanks. didn't know.